# "null" logic error - Java

Tags: java, null, logic

Hi so I'm relatively new at Java, I have about 2 months of experience, so please try to answer my question using terms and code relevant to my learning level.

So, I have to make a program for school that makes a letter, fitting the following format:

```
Dear recipient name:

blank line

first line of the body

second line of the body

.  .  .

last line of the body

blank line

Sincerely,

blank line

sender name
```

my code looks like this:

```
 private String body;
    private String letter;

    public Letter(String from, String to)
    {
        letter = ("Dear " + to + ":" + "\n" + "\n" + body + "\n" + "Sincerely," + "\n" + "\n" + from);
        body = "";
    }

    public void addLine(String line)
    {
        body = body + line + "\n";
    }

    public String getText()
    {
        return letter;
    }
```

Ive tried several different ways to get this program done, and the one that yields the best results is this one.. The thing is, we're only supposed to use two instance fields max. It seems that it's null because body isn't given a value in my constructor. There's also a program tester class that looks like this:

```
public class LetterTester

{

   public static void main(String [] args)

   {

       Letter tyler = new Letter("Mary", "John");

       tyler.addLine("I am sorry we must part.");

       tyler.addLine("I wish you all the best.");

       System.out.println(tyler.getText());

   }

}
```

i skipped all the default stuff and some braces and theres no syntax errors, but when i run the tester class, I get:

```
Dear John:

null
Sincerely,

Mary
```

What am I doing wrong, and can someone please give a solution as to how to get rid of null? Keep in mind I can only use two instance fields, thanks.

Comment: ` body = body;` inside your constructor !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`body` is `null` because that is the default value for reference fields. You could initialize it to empty string `body = ""` instead. That would work with your `addLine()` code. You should also move constructing the content from the constructor to `getText()`. In the constructor the required data is not yet available.

Also consider using a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html). That's usually better choise than `+` when you need to make several concatenations.

**Edit:** (after a clarifying comment by the OP, and myself reading the question better)

In the constructor you can start the letter like:

```
body = "Dear " + to + ":" + "\n\n";
sender = from;
```

Here I made `sender` a field. You don't need the `letter` field, so you can still stay at the max 2 fields limit.

Comment: Yes but in getText, I can't use the to and from parameter variables that are in the constructor, that's my problem.

Comment: @Crazykid0416 You don't need to store the `to` variable anywhere, since it's needed only in the beginning. So you can simply add it to your initial `body`. (Or the `StringBuilder`). So the only fields you need is something to store `from`, and the contents of the letter so far.

Comment: so my instance fields should be something representing the entire letter, and a variable representing from?

Comment: @Crazykid0416 exactly :-) I was amending the answer while you wrote the comment. (StringBuilder is still a better implementation, but I don't know what you're supposed to know at this stage of education).

Comment: do you mind helping me with the class part of the code? im not sure how one would code it, it would help a lot. I know the instance fields are from and letter but where would they go, and how would i use it?

Comment: Wow thank you so much that helped, i finished the project. Thanks for all the help, I understand how it works now!

Comment: OK! You're welcome :-). Remember to accept the answer if it solved the problem. And welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to initialize the `body` variable with an empty string. Otherwise its initialized as `null`, and thereby you cannot append anything to the string as you are doing in function `addLine()`

Comment: i tried doing that, replacing body=body to body="" and nothing works, it gives the same null result.